# How should I navigate to record details page instead of record list view when hit "save" button after entering new record?

Tags: lightning

my question here is when we enter new record in salesforce using page layout and hit save button it displays the list view of all records created by user and then user selects the particular record to view the details, I would like user to directly route to record detail page instead list view.

Comment: Can you add more context as to from where are you creating this new record. From the list view New button or related list New button or somewhere else ?

Comment: I am trying to create a record from New button available on List view of an object, new->fill in details->save

Comment: Are you using Salesforce Lightning UI, or Salesforce Classic UI?